# Summing elements of array

Tags: java, runtime-error

I have written a code for a question. The questions says the user would enter first a int which would be number of elements than the user enters elements and program shows it sum.
My program works fine in Netbeans but is giving run time errors in Online compilers.
Here's the code

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args){
  long sum=0 ;
    Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
    int not=a.nextInt();
    Scanner b=new Scanner (System.in);
    String st=b.nextLine();
    int[] ty=new int[not];
    for(int i=0;i<not;i++)
    {
        String[] u=st.split(" ");
        String uo=u[i];
        long num=Long.parseLong(uo);
        sum=num+sum;

    }
    System.out.println(sum);



} }
```

The error message goes

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:12)
```

If anyone could tell me my mistake it would very good.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What online compiler are you testing? Ideone?

Comment: Are you importing the right libs?

Comment: Are you importing java.util.Scanner; ?

Comment: Yes I've imported right libs and I'm testing it on HackerRank Compiler

Comment: try on this site http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: What is the runtime error you are getting?

Comment: Do you have the option test against custom input checked?

Comment: Sorry for  forgetting  to mention it but now i've done it in the questions itself

Comment: Yes, I tried it too but same error message came

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues with your code -

1. You are splitting the second line inside the for loop, you should split the `st` string outside the for loop (above it) and then iterate through it in the for loop.
2. You are defining two scanners, but you actually do not need to define two, you can remove the scanner `b` and just use scanner `a` for taking all inputs.
3. When you are doing `a.nextInt()` you read in the int, but the file handle does not automatically go onto the next line, it still stays at right after the int you read , and there is a new line still to be read. Hence, when you do `a.nextLine()` after that you only get newline from the current line. You actually need to do `a.nextLine()` one time (discard the output) and do it again.

Comment: Is there any thing a.nextLint()??

Comment: No, I do not think so

Comment: I did as you said(except the third thing) but now it shows: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:601)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
 at Solution.main(Solution.java:19)

Comment: But you've written in your solution a.nextLint.